# How to handle large dataset that exceeds the RAM Size on Google Colab?

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata, google-colaboratory

I am working on a dataset from a book reviews website which includes around 225 million user-item interactions. Now I am supposed to design a Collaborative Filtering based Recommendation System on this dataset. But I cannot load the dataset on Google Colab due to its size. Everytime I run `pd.read_json()`, it crashes the runtime and gets restarted. Can anyone help me out in here?

I tried this code in the notebook.

```
df = pd.read_json('/content/data/dataset.json')
df.head()
```

And it crashed the runtime.

Comment: `read_json()` allows you to read the file in chunks and process each chunk. Maybe this would be useful. How large is the file?

Comment: The file is 15.5 GB in size, around 15.3 mil lines. Will dividing it in the chunks be able to show the distribution? Like sampling error and other such things will come into play. I am a student and new to this field, so I don't know much in detail.

Comment: Reading the file in chunks means just that. You get say half the data, do whatever analysis you want/can on that half and then repeat. How useful that is depends on the data and the required analysis. As another idea you could look into using Polars or Pyspark which can handle large datasets; the syntax is somewhat different from Pandas but you can do the same things in different ways -  both can read in a json file.